# Regra para validar registro de valores PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$newprice = $ob->pennyauction == 1 ? $oldprice + 0.01 : $oldprice + $plusprice;
```

Eu preciso que ele realize a seguinte verificação, antes de exibir o valor de **`$newprice`**.

A regra é evitar que seja gravado no DB o mesmo valor, por exemplo se em `$oldprice` já tiver **0.02** e ele tentar gravar o **0.02** novamente, a regra deve adicionar **+ 0.01**.

Ele já faz isso ali, mas as vezes ocorre de executar exatamente ao mesmo tempo, então ele insere os valores iguais, ai entra essa regra para validar isso.

Existe algo para implementar ali?

Comment: Vai depender, **executar exatamente ao mesmo tempo** .. você quer dizer que varias usuários ao mesmo tempo ? Ou você esta executando um loop ?

Comment: Vários usuários ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Ao executar adicionar em uma fila de execução server side em vez de executar na na hora deve prevenir isso

Comment: @AnthraxisBR Tem exemplos disso? Não faço ideia do que seja.

Comment: Veja se isso resolve: https://www.exakat.io/prevent-multiple-php-scripts-at-the-same-time/ lock file é mais simples do que criar essa lista

Comment: Rapaz, li tudo o que diz nesse site e não entendi exatamente o que ele vai fazer. Vai impedir que o arquivo seja executado ao mesmo tempo pelos usuários?

Comment: Sim, quando executar um script, criar um arquivo e quando terminar ele remove, e se tentar executar ao mesmo tempo ele tentar criar esse arquivo, se ele existir ele não deixa executar, vou fazer uma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso de duas formas, com uma fila de execução, ou com um arquivo para travar a execução simultanea, a ideia é:

**1** - Ao executar, criar um arquivo .lock (pode ser qualquer extensão de arquivo, mas vamos usar **.lock**)

**2** - Executar o script de verdade

**3** - Ao terminar remover o arquivo

**Exemplo:**

```
if (mkdir('/tmp/prevent.lock', 0700)) {
    funcaoDaRegra();
    rmdir('/tmp/prevent.lock');
} else {

    funcaoPreventiva();
}

function funcaoDaRegra() {
    //Faça aqui o que deve ser feito sem duplicar
    echo 'Aqui a função foi executada';
}

function funcaoPreventiva() {
    //De uma resposta ao usuário caso tenha sido prevenida a duplicação
    echo 'Aqui prevenimos a execução dupla';
}
```

OBS: Caso esteja usando servidor windows, use mkdir com o terceiro parametro:

```
mkdir('/tmp/prevent.lock', 0700,true)
```

Comment: Mas isso não seria problemático, já que o meu arquivo é executado praticamente a cada segundo?

Comment: MAs elas é a cada segundo 100% do tempo ? pra não ter muitas respostas de erro, na solicitação, em vez de responder que não pode ser executada de primeira, tenta umas 3 vezes num intervalo rapido, dificilmente vai parar.

Comment: Então.. trata-se de um sistema de leilão de centavos. O arquivo será executado várias vezes somente quando um leilão iniciar. Se não tiver nenhum leilão rodando ele não vai ser executado várias vezes.

Comment: Eu tentei implementar mas não funcionou muito bem.

Comment: Como assim não funcionou muito bem ? faz um ideone de como você tentou aplicar